# What are some good strategies to launch a token in a DEX?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider

I have a project that has a token and I want to launch it in a DEX.

How can I incentivise users to provide liquidity to the pool so the pool is backed by a fair amount of WETH? Do you know of some good resources on strategies and best practices to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to increase the liquidity for your token at the launch

- The easiest way is provide the liquidity yourself. Just supply your token and ETH or USDC as a quote token.
- [Liquidity mining](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/liquidity-mining) is a popular way by paying people to provide liquidity for your [AMM](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/amm) pairs.
- [Airdrops](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/airdrop) might attract people that start to trade your tokens. However more than often this backfires.
- You can hire a professional market maker. But unless your project is high quality, attracting professional market makers might be difficult.

Note that all the liquidity increasing options have a cost associated with them. It's unlikely no one is going to help you unless you pay them.